# Python `Enum` with `__eq__` method no longer hashable

Tags: python, hash, enums

**TLDR:**

- Is there a way to compare enums to their value?
- Is this an anti-pattern?
- Can I avoid in long `if..elif..elif..else` chain in the `get_sound` of the final example below?

---

**Details:**

I have a piece of code that I want to change so that it uses `Enum`s instead of (until now) strings. For backwards compatibility however, I'd like the user to be able to still use strings as well, and I cannot get it to work. The issue is that, the way I've implemented it, I need an `__eq__` that causes my enum to no longer be hashable.

Ok, time for an example. Contrived, of course.

##### Until now

```py
def can_fly(animal: str) -> bool:
    if animal == 'duck':
        return True
    if animal in ['cat', 'cow']:
        return False
    raise ValueError("``animal`` must be 'cat', 'cow', or 'duck'.")

def get_sound(animal: str) -> str:
    return {'cow': 'MOOO', 'cat': 'miauw', 'duck': 'Quack!'}[animal]
```

This works; `can_fly('cat')` returns `False` and `get_sound('cat')` returns `'miauw'`.

##### Now, changed to Enum

```py
from enum import Enum, auto

class Animal(Enum):
    COW = auto()
    CAT = auto()
    DUCK = auto()

def can_fly(animal: Animal) -> bool:
    if animal is Animal.DUCK:
        return True
    if animal in [Animal.CAT, Animal.COW]:
        return False
    raise ValueError("``animal`` must be member of Animal.")

def get_sound(animal: Animal) -> str:
    return {Animal.COW: 'MOOO', Animal.CAT: 'miauw', Animal.DUCK: 'Quack!'}[animal]
```

This also works: `can_fly(Animal.CAT)` returns `False` and `get_sound(Animal.CAT)` returns `'miauw'`.

However, I can no longer do `can_fly('cat')` or `get_sound('cat')`.

##### Partial solution using `__eq__`

I tried to solve this by allowing comparison with `==`:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Animal(Enum):
    COW = 'cow'
    CAT = 'cat'
    DUCK = 'duck'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self is other or self.value == other

def can_fly(animal: Animal) -> bool:
    if animal == Animal.DUCK:
        return True
    if animal in [Animal.CAT, Animal.COW]:
        return False
    raise ValueError("``animal`` must be member of Animal.")

def get_sound(animal: Animal) -> str:
    return {Animal.COW: 'MOOO', Animal.CAT: 'miauw', Animal.DUCK: 'Quack!'}[animal]
```

Here, both `can_fly('cat')` and `can_fly(Animal.CAT)` return `False`. However, `get_sound('cat')` still does not work.

**Is there a way to get this to work, apart from with the obvious `if..elif..`-chain?**

**What are the best practices in this situation?**

---

Edit: I found a solution that is close to what I'm looking for, see below.

Comment: Regarding `__eq__` and `__hash__`: *"A class that overrides `__eq__()` and does not define `__hash__()` will have its `__hash__()` implicitly set to `None`."*.  So in general, if you ever override `__eq__` you should consider overriding `__hash__` as well.  See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

Comment: You know that it's easy to create instances of the enum from the corresponding string name, right? All you need is e.g. `Animal['CAT']`. Or `Animal('cat')`, given the `CAT = 'cat'` version of the code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I did not know that... So I guess I can make my answer (below) even shorter and remove the `classmethod` alltogether. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I thought of ***an*** answer as soon as I posted.

Which was improved further by Brian's comment.

This is the current solution, and I don't see how it could be improved any further:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Animal(Enum):
    COW = 'cow'
    CAT = 'cat'
    DUCK = 'duck'

def can_fly(animal: Animal) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(animal, Animal):
        animal = Animal(animal)
    if animal is Animal.DUCK:
        return True
    if animal in [Animal.CAT, Animal.COW]:
        return False
    raise ValueError("``animal`` must be member of Animal.")

def get_sound(animal: Animal) -> str:
    if not isinstance(animal, Animal):
        animal = Animal(animal)
    return {Animal.COW: 'MOOO', Animal.CAT: 'miauw', Animal.DUCK: 'Quack!'}[animal]
```

Once all users have migrated to using the Enum only, I can remove the first two lines of both functions.

More than halve of the words on the functions' first 3 lines (incl. signature) are `animal` or `Animal` which looks a bit bewildering. But I guess that's really unavoidable.

Comment: Your `from_value` class method seems to have the same function as just invoking the enum's constructor: `Animal("cat")` is the same as `Animal.from_value("cat")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Animal(Enum):
    #
    def __new__(cls, sound, can_fly):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = len(cls._member_names_) + 1
        member.sound = sound
        member.can_fly = can_fly
        return member
    #
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        return cls[value.upper()]
    #
    COW = 'MOOO', False
    CAT = 'miauw', False
    DUCK = 'Quack!', True

def can_fly(animal) -> bool:
    try:
        return Animal(animal).can_fly
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("``animal`` must be 'cat', 'cow', or 'duck'.") from None

def get_sound(animal) -> str:
    return Animal(animal).sound
```

and in use:

```
>>> can_fly(Animal.COW)
False

>>> can_fly('cat')
False

>>> can_fly('mouse')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in can_fly
ValueError: ``animal`` must be 'cat', 'cow', or 'duck'.

>>> get_sound('DUCK')
'Quack!'
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Can you explain the `__new__` override?

Comment: @DanielWalker the `__new__` override in the example is exactly the same as in the documentation - it's well explain in the docs. It's just the mandatory `__new__` boilerplate calling the superclass and setting the `obj._value_` so it's working exactly like `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of 0x5453's comment (which was also news to me), you can solve this easily by providing a `__hash__` method:

```py
class Animal(Enum):
    COW = 'cow'
    CAT = 'cat'
    DUCK = 'duck'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self is other or self.value == other

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

'cow' in {Animal.COW} # True
```

You can also use dual-inheritance:

```py
class Animal(str, Enum):
    COW = 'cow'
    CAT = 'cat'
    DUCK = 'duck'
```

This way, `Animal`s **are** strings.

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper that normalizes other ways to specify the value, into instances of the enum. For example:

```
class Animal(Enum):
    COW = auto()
    CAT = auto()
    DUCK = auto()

def normalized(animal: Union[Animal, int, str]) -> Animal:
    if isinstance(animal, Animal):
        return animal
    if isinstance(animal, str): # assume it's a symbolic name
        return Animal[animal]
    if isinstance(animal, int): # assume it's one of the auto() values
        return Animal(animal)
    raise TypeError("must give an Animal, animal name or animal value")
```

Then use that result as usual:

```
def can_fly(animal: Union[Animal, int, str]) -> bool:
    return normalized(animal) in {Animal.DUCK}

def get_sound(animal: Union[Animal, int, str]) -> str:
    return {Animal.COW: 'MOOO', Animal.CAT: 'miauw', Animal.DUCK: 'Quack!'}[normalized(animal)]
```

We don't need any more error checking than that, because the Animal constructor and indexer already do all the needed error checking.

---

However, it would be better to implement functionality like `can_fly` and `get_sound` as methods on the enum. We can even use properties:

```
class Animal(Enum):
    COW = (False, 'MOOO')
    CAT = (False, 'miauw')
    DUCK = (True, 'Quack!')

    def __init__(self, flight, sound):
        self._flight = flight
        self._sound = sound

    @property
    def can_fly(self):
        return self._flight

    @property
    def sound(self):
        return self._sound
```

And now we can do:

```
>>> Animal.COW.can_fly
False
>>> Animal['CAT'].sound
'miauw'
```